# Error in SQL trigger query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

UPDATED:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateWage BEFORE UPDATE ON st_penalty
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF DAY({fw NOW( ) } ) = 1 THEN
     UPDATE st_penalty SET st_penalty.wage = (SELECT wage FROM staff WHERE staff.memId = st_penalty.memId);
  END IF;
END$$
```

The error is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6.

Comment: try using day(NOW()) = 1 instead of fwNOW()

Comment: No difference. The error is following "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN (DAY(NOW()) =1) ON st_penalty FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE st_penalty SE' at line 2"

Comment: I see no reason why the trigger should be giving #1064 error?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html), there's no "WHEN" clause in MySql triggers. Also, you've missed AFTER/BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE actions.

I'd write your trigger somewhat like this (may not compile):

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateWage AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON st_penalty
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (DAY(NOW()) = 1)
       UPDATE st_penalty SET st_penalty.wage = (SELECT wage FROM staff WHERE staff.memId = st_penalty.memId) WHERE st_penalty.ID = new.ID
END;
```

new variable contains the newly added/updated values for row. I'd recommend you reading more from the link above about writing triggers.

Comment: put semicolon after END IF:

END IF;
END